# Does the blog image imply that being welcoming ends here?

Tags: discussion, blog, code-of-conduct

[image]

The image for [the blog post announcing the CoC](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/) as used on https://stackoverflow.blog/ displays a unicorn holding a flag saying

```
</welcome>
```

Does this mean that being welcoming ends here?

Or does this mean that all is said and done about `welcome`? Did the 'Welcome Wagon' reach its destination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It just means that after you've welcomed a (new) user, you can go ahead and try to solve their problem (while still adhering to the [Code of Conduct](/conduct), of course). If we'd keep on welcoming them, they would never get a solution to their problem...

Comment: @intenti Unicorns are everywhere.